# Calling array getting error: undefined is not an object

Tags: reactjs, redux, native, redux-thunk

There is some issue with my reducer. I can pull from the database array on command+S but when I do a hard refresh it cannot find the data.

1. And I get error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'quizFire[0]')

I can load the array quizFire, I just can't call any of its elements. I've tried a number of options but I am not sure if I'm not storing or calling the database correctly.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import { View, Text, } from 'react-native';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import * as paidRoundActionFire from '../store/action/paidRoundAction';

const ThirdRound = props =>{

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(paidRoundActionFire.fetchProducts());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const quizFire = useSelector(state => state.paidQuiz.questionsFire);

  return(
    <View> 
      <Text>
      {quizFire[0].answer1}
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
}
export default ThirdRound;
```

```
//Store Reducer

import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { SET_QUESTIONS } from '../action/paidRoundAction';

var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window'); 
//const incrementToMoveForward = (width+30)/20;

const initialState = {
//totalCount: questions.length,
questionsFire: [],
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    //state.activeQuestionIndex + 1;
    switch (action.type) {

    case SET_QUESTIONS: {
        return {
            questionsFire: action.questionsFireRecall,
        }
    }    
    default:
      return {state};
  }


};
```

```
//Store Action

import Questions from "../../models/questions";

export const SET_QUESTIONS = 'SET_QUESTIONS';



export const fetchProducts = () => {

    return async dispatch => {
        try {
            //any async code you want
        const response = await fetch(
           'https://my-quiz-questions.firebaseio.com/questions.json',) 

    const resData = await response.json(); 
    console.log("async/await based");
    const loadedQuestions = [];

        for (const key in resData) {
            loadedQuestions.push(
                new Questions(
                key,
                resData[key].answer1,
                resData[key].answer2,
                resData[key].answer3,
                resData[key].correctAnswer,
                resData[key].explanation,
                resData[key].question

                )
            )
        }


    dispatch({ type: SET_QUESTIONS, questionsFireRecall: loadedQuestions });
        }

    catch (err) {
        // send to custom analytics server
        throw err;
      }
    };
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning you have `quizFire` set as empty array `[]`. But you want to render some item from this empty array and this is undefined. Try to render it like `quizFire.length && quizFire[0].something`

Why are you putting `dispatch` as useEffect deps? Because litter is telling you to do that or you did it in purpose?